# I am trying autocomplete google place using search bar and not any git hub code

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, autocomplete, google-places-api

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

NSString *searchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&sensor=true&key=*******",searching.text];

searchQuery = [searchQuery stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:searchQuery];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

}
```

I am a fresh candidate and have no idea how to move with it. Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answere myself...............